# How to show/hide a div independently among others with the same class name within a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

i have a while loop within an SQL query that returns all `comments` for a specific `post page` , within that same loop i have another query and a while loop that searches for `replies` to that `comment` and returns only the first row using `LIMIT 1`. I did this so only one `reply` is shown for a `comment` at first, i added another another query and a loop within the second loop to search for other `replies` to the `comment` except this time I'm returning the other rows except the first row using `LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615`. I've put the result of the last query in a div which is hidden at first, and a trigger `view all replies` in the first query which comes before the hidden div.

So now i have a trigger `view all replies` inside the first loop (that contains the comments). using javascript i can show and hide the div when the trigger is clicked. this is a snapshot of what it looks like

**First snapshot, div is hidden with only 1 reply being shown.**
[image]

**second snapshot, div is visible and text for `trigger` is changed**
[image]

**My problem:**
Since I'm using the same class for all hidden `div's`, the trigger for a particular `comment` to show/hide its `replies` works for all `comments`. so when i click on `view all replies` for the first comment, the `replies` for the second,third etc are shown as well. How do rewrite my code to target specific comments to show/hide its replies?

**JavaScript**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var showText='View all replies';
var hideText='Hide';
// initialise the visibility check
var is_visible = false;
// append show/hide links 
$('.view1').prev().append();
$(".licom").hide(); 
$(".view1").click(function(){
// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;
// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
$('.licom').toggle(function() {
$(this).closest('view1').find('.licom').hide();
return false;
 },
function() {
$(this).closest("view1").next(".licom").show();
return false;
 });  
    });          
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**info.php**

```
  <?php
  ...........
   $stmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT *
  FROM comment
  WHERE post_id = :pid
  ");

$stmt->bindParam(":pid", $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$stmt->execute();

while($obj = $stmt->fetch()){
     $username = $obj['user_name'];
      $comment = $obj['comment'];
      $id1 = $obj['id'];
      $userimage = $obj['user_image'];
      $row ++;
      $likes = $obj['like1'];
      $dislikes = $obj['dislike'];
  echo '<div class="txt">';
  echo '<div class="comment-container">';
  echo '<div class="comment-item">';
    echo '<div class="comment-avatar">';
      echo '<img src="user/user_images/'.$userimage.'" alt="avatar">';
    echo '</div>';
     echo '<div class="comment-post">';
      echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$username.'&nbsp&nbspsaid....  
     </span>';
      echo '<p style="margin-left:-11px;">'.$comment.'</p>';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<form action="" method="post" class="ajaxform"   
           enctype="multipart/form-data">';

       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="'.$type_id.'">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="stk" value="'.$likes.'">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15"
          value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;margin-
             right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';

      echo '</form>';
      echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">';
       echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkd_id" value="'.$id.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="dislike" value="">';
        echo ' <input type= "image" id="submit" src="images/dislike.png" 
              width="15" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;
              margin-top:-14px;margin-right:230px;"/>
             <div class="ldks">'.$dislikes.'</div>';
             echo '</form>';
             //trigger to hide/show replies
             echo '<span class="view1" style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">View all replies</span>';
             //
            echo '<span class="SendCopy">Reply</span> ';
            echo '<div class="users">';
           echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-
                  data">';
           echo '<textarea rows="4"  name="replycomment" style="float:right;
                  resize: none;margin-top:5px;" cols="50" >';
            echo '</textarea>';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';
         echo '<input type="submit" name="reply" id="submit" class="post-
                 button" value="Send" />';
         echo '</form>';

          echo '</div>';

         echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';  

         echo '</div>'; 
        echo '</div>';

 //Relpy to comment, show only the first row
 $rep = $conn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM reply WHERE comment_id = :comid LIMIT 1");
$rep->bindParam(":pid", $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$rep->execute();

while($obj = $rep->fetch()){
    //...........same output as first without the view all replies trigger......

//Relpy to comment, show from 2-
$rep = $conn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM reply WHERE comment_id = :comid LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615");
$rep->bindParam(":pid", $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$rep->execute();

while($obj = $rep->fetch()){
//div to show/hide
echo '<div class="licom">';
 //...........same output as first without the view all replies trigger......

}
  }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've changed my triggers to be unique

```
echo'<a href="#" id="licom-'.$id1.'">View all replies</a>';
```

and my div class to show/hide to be unique as well by group.

```
echo '<div class="licom licom-'.$cc_id.'">';//$cc_id has the same value as trigger. example $id1=2, $cc_id=2.
```

now i have the trigger as `licom-1` and div to show/hide as `licom licom-1`

then i changed my javascript to:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('.'+id).css('display') == 'none')
    {
        $('.'+id).css('display','block');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.'+id).css('display','none');
    }
     return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
       })
   })
  </script>
```

This javascript would only show/hide the div with same `licom` value i.e only the replies with same `id` would be toggled by that trigger.

and lastly to make all `licom` hidden, i added the css.

```
  .licom  {
            display:none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a unique comment ID, you could add that as an ID attribute to your comment-container element, similar to this:

`echo '<div class="comment-container" id="comment-' . $id . '">';`

Then, your jQuery for toggling the comments (only within that container) would look something like this:

```
//When a user clicks "View all replies"...
$('.view1').click(function() {
    //Find the ID of the comment container he/she clicked inside
    var commentID = $(this).closest('.comment-container').attr('id');

    //Use that ID to make the selector more specific when targeting the reply elements
    $('#' + commentID + ' .licom').toggle();
});
```

In other words, your jQuery/CSS selector just needs to be more specific.

Also, if you want to add a little bit of (subtle) animation to the show/hide behavior, jQuery's `toggle()` function accepts several options for accomplishing this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

---

### UPDATE

I just realized that your `.licom` elements are not inside the `.comment-container` element like I originally assumed. So here's a modified version of my answer that allows you to keep your existing HTML structure.

In addition to outputting the comment ID as the `id` attribute on the `.comment-container` (that first line of PHP in my original answer), you also need to output it as a class on each `.licom`, like this:

`echo '<div class="licom comment-' . $id . '">';`

Then, the jQuery looks like this:

```
//When a user clicks "View all replies"...
$('.view1').click(function() {
    //Find the ID of the comment container he/she clicked inside
    var commentID = $(this).closest('.comment-container').attr('id');

    //Use that ID to make the selector more specific when targeting the reply elements
    $('.licom.' + commentID).toggle();
});
```

Comment: i'm not good at JavaScript, could you show an example of how to do this? I'll  appreciate it

Comment: @chris94 I updated the JavaScript example in my answer. Try that out.

Comment: i've just tried your code, nothing happens when i click on `view all replies`. i think its because `view all replies ` comes way before the `div` its suppose to hide.

Comment: Hmm... I tested this and it works but your HTML structure may be different than I expected. Did you see any errors in the browser's JS console? You might wanna try `console.log(commentID);` to see if it's getting the correct value. Also, I'm assuming you're using this JS in combination with that first line of PHP that I posted in my answer.

Comment: yes i used your php code to replace mine but changed  `$id ` to  `$id1 ` to match my own variable name. Also in the JavaScript console, I'm getting  `undefined `

Comment: Hey @chris94, I updated my answer again. Please see if that works.

Comment: thanks for your support :) . This problem has already been solved, i'll be posting the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

$('.licom').toggle()... is too broad and will select all elements with the 'licom' class, regardless of whether or not they were inside of the element that was clicked. Try $(this).children('.licom') instead.

Comment: i cant see the replies anymore.